# ios - fast loading images/videos from phone with swift (like instagram does)

Tags: ios, swift, image, performance

I am building an app where you can pick images from your phone or make new ones with the camera. The question is about picking internal images. First I was using ImagepickerController where a new Controller pops up and I can select the image I want. Later I decided to change that design approach, but to embed all the pictures from my phone inside the main screen (the one that shows when you enter the app) where you can select each image by just tapping on it (so no new controller pops up). And there is the problem. Reading pictures and loading them inside my collectionview takes just too much time (reading pictures is the main issue). I have over 1000 pictures on my phone, and it takes like 7 seconds for the app to read 100 pictures (than it crashes, not sure why, maybe some memory issue, didnt look further into it bcz my main problem was the reading performance).

For reading I am using `PHAssetCollection`, this is the code:

```
let allPhotosResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)

let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

allPhotosResult.enumerateObjects({(object: AnyObject!,
        count: Int,
        stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

        if object is PHAsset{
            let imgAsset = object as! PHAsset

            countI += 1
            if countI > 100 {
                return
            }

            let imageSize = CGSize(width: imgAsset.pixelWidth,
                                   height: imgAsset.pixelHeight)


            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.isSynchronous = true

            imageManager.requestImage(for: imgAsset,
                                      targetSize: imageSize,
                                      contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                      options: options,
                                      resultHandler: {
                                        (image, info) -> Void in

                                            self._images.append(image!)


                                        }

            })

        }
    })
```

I quit at 100 images bcz then they are being displayed, but again thats not the issue I think I will be able to solve that.

So, is there a faster way to read all the images and load them as thumbnails into my collectionview ? I didnt have any of the popular photos apps, but I downloaded some of them to see how their performance is, and Instagram is pretty impressive. All the images are there without any delay, which means there must be a way to get them all pretty fast. Maybe they fetch them in the background even when the app is not running ?

Regards

P.S. - ah yes, I know I can execute the reading async, but that doesnt solve my problem bcz the delay will still be there

Comment: just do one thing that when you fetch all image set its size like 100*100 or 175*175 dont go for high resolution if you go with hight resolution then your app crush with memory issue./

Comment: I agree with @HimanshuMoradiya. Also, load a small number of images and implement the ability to load more images when the user scrolls down something like 60% of the available images so that way you're only loading a few images at a time.

Comment: @Vlad if he load with thumbail size image then i think he can not face memory issue while he fetch 1000 image .

Comment: So you think when I load small images, and set the limit to say 400, when the user scrolls to image 250 i should load again 400 and so on ... As I said, on Instagram I dont see and loading circle or smt like that (I was scrolling really fast but nothing, and thats why I thought that all of them are being loaded at once) , but maybe it reloads so fast that I dont see it. Thanks I will try that  out

Comment: @rimes did you solve your problem or not some more information about this

Comment: a yes, I did, thanks. The important part here is also that my abort function after 100 entries was not doing what i waned. I wanted it to stop fetching, but instead it still run for every picture, but didnt just fetch the image. So by fixing the abort statement and using your approach its working

Comment: I also implement a photo picker for my app similar to yours. Have you taken a look at the Photos kit example from Apple? The trick is that the picker needs to dynamically cache a number of thumbnail images, and remove the ones not in view port from the cache. Follow the example here will give you a better idea.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html

Also, the magic number for thumbnail size is 250 to use with PHImageCachingManager. The picker had huge memory impact in my app when size > 250.